# Dynamic linq to sql "GroupBy" query results parsing

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am using Dynamic Linq to sql(microsoft provided dynamic.cs) and created successfully "Groupby" query

```
var Result = le.Table.where(e,value[]).GroupBy("Applicationname","it");

foreach(var i in Result)
{
    foreach(var t in i)
    {
        //want to do my work 
    }
}
```

I get first groups in `i`, but when `i` run second foreach loop it gives error
that "object doesn't not contain a public definition for getenumerator".
In debugger I am getting value but don't know how to parse it. I want to view each single entry of each group.

Pls help

Thank You

Comment: Can't you access your values via dot-notation? Instead second `foreach` do a `i.fieldname1`, `i.fieldname2` etc. Or you don't know in advance what the fields would be?

Comment: no i cant. i was successfully doing it in static linq query, but in dynamic linq this error is coming "object does not contain public definition........"